# Enyim Memcached Client Caching same item on multiple servers

Tags: memcached

We have a memecached cluster of 5 servers.  When we reviewed the cache keys it shows that the same item is showing up across 4-5 servers in the cluster.  As I understand it, Enyim's default key hash is supposed to be guaranteed consistent.  Other than the servers being marked as down, I am at a loss to understand what the issue could be.  Any suggestions?